# Is there a method that allows me to print an array without the commas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have the following code in JavaScript:

```
let calculationsArray = [];
$('.number-1').on('click', ()=> {
  calculationsArray.push(1);
  document.getElementById('screen-text').innerHTML = calculationsArray;
})
$('.number-2').on('click', ()=> {
  calculationsArray.push(2);
  document.getElementById('screen-text').innerHTML = calculationsArray;
})
```

And the following code in HTML:

```
<span id='screen-text'></span>
```

But when the code runs, it prints like this: 1,2. Is there a way to print the array so it shows up without commas, like this: 12? I know a way to do it is to replace calculationsArray after innerHTML with the number specified but when I try that, it replaces the number before. For example, if I replace calculationsArray, and I press the 1 button and 2 button, it starts like this: 1, but after I press the 2 button, it replaces the 1 with 2 like this: 2. I want it to append the 2 after the 1, like so: 12.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 2):

You can use join try this:

```
calculationsArray.join("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.

```js
let calculationsArray = [];
$('.number-1').on('click', () => {
  calculationsArray.push(1);
  document.getElementById('screen-text').innerHTML =calculationsArray.join('');
})
$('.number-2').on('click', () => {
  calculationsArray.push(2);
  document.getElementById('screen-text').innerHTML =calculationsArray.join('');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='screen-text'></span>
<button class="number-1">1</button>
<button class="number-2">2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you can use `.join()` with whatever string you want as the separator.

But also, you don't need repetitive code like that. Just select all the elements, give them the same handler, and extract the number from the class name.

```
let calculationsArray = [];
$('[class*=number-]').on('click', (event)=> {
  const n = +event.currentTarget.className.match(/\bnumber-(\d+)\b/)[1];
  calculationsArray.push(n);
  document.getElementById('screen-text').innerHTML = calculationsArray.join("");
});
```